# Google Appscript Email Range with Format not Working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to email a range as a table with the same format as in the sheet, I got it where it sends a table but it will display any blank space as the word  "None" and no format is being added.

I've been looking for a correct solution on this, and there are a few answers that worked well but without the correct formatting to the table, any suggestions?

Below my code:

```
function sendMail(){
var shh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = shh.getSheetByName('Email');
 var data = sh.getRange("A1:J34").getValues();
  //var htmltable =[];

var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" dir="ltr" border="1" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;'
var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT +' ">';

for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++){

htmltable += '<tr>';

for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
  if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + 'None' + '</td>';} 
  else
    if (row === 0)  {
      htmltable += '<th>' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
    }

  else {htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
}

     htmltable += '</tr>';
}

     htmltable += '</table>';
     Logger.log(data);
     Logger.log(htmltable);
MailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com', 'Daily report','' ,{htmlBody: htmltable})
}
```

Comment: That's what you're telling it to do with the line `if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + 'None' + '</td>';}`

Comment: The formatting actually works, I tried to replace Arial with Times New Roman and the font changed. Can you tell us which of the formatting you have placed in the HTML does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my replication, the HTML formatting is correct, so only the hardcoded "None" value needs to be replaced. You can put a single white space like this:

> EDIT: You would need to use `getBackgrounds` on the range then copy the array elements into the HTML string in the loop.

```
function sendMail(){
var shh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = shh.getSheetByName('Email');
var r = sh.getRange('A1:J34');
var data = r.getValues();
var bgcolors = r.getBackgrounds();

...

for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
  // put white space when empty
  if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td style="background-color:' + bgcolors[row][col] + ';">' + ' ' + '</td>';} 
  else
    if (row === 0)  {
      htmltable += '<th style="background-color:' + bgcolors[row][col] + ';">' + data[row][col] + '</th>';
    }

  else {htmltable += '<td style="background-color:' + bgcolors[row][col] + ';">' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Carlos, yeah I totally missed that, what's not replicating is the Cell Background color

Comment: I see. I edited the answer to get the background color of each cell and copy it to the HTML output.

Comment: Brilliant, nice method of .getBackgrounds, I appreciate it